# Swig+Java: namespaces and packages

Tags: java, c++, namespaces, package, swig

Assume the C++ class structure like this:

```
namespace MainNS
{
    namespace A
    {
        class Class
        {
            //...
        };
    }

    namespace B
    {
        class Class
        {
            //...
        };
    }

    //...
}
```

I have followed this SWIG docs: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Java.html#Java_namespaces

In interface files I define the following to create packages on Java side:

```
%nspace MainNS::A::Class
%nspace MainNS::B::Class
```

and then have to use `java` pragma to place the JNI file into "appropriate" place (somewhere where classes can access it - that's the core of the problem, please see below):

```
%pragma(java) jniclasspackage = "MainNS::A" //or "MainNS::B"
```

Now, everyone from class `MainNS::A::Class` (package `MainNS.A`) can access generated `<modulename>JNI` class.

However, namespace `B` ended up in different package `MainNS::B` and `MainNS::B::Class` (package `MainNS.B`) can't access `<modulename>JNI` class.

What is the solution for this problem? As far as I understand there is no SWIG option to split the generated JNI class with native function signatures?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old thread, but since I came across a similar issue:

the way I would solve this is to create two different modules, A and B (and so two different swig interface files A.i and B.i). you can import each file (use %import not %include)

```
%module A 
%{
    #include <MainNS/A.hxx>
%}
%feature(nspace);
%pragma(java) jniclasspackage="MainNS.A";

%import "B.i"
%include <MainNS/A.hxx>
```

Then B.i:

```
%module B 
%{
    #include <MainNS/B.hxx>
%}
%feature(nspace);
%pragma(java) jniclasspackage="MainNS.B";

%import "A.i"
%include <MainNS/B.hxx>
```

Links:

- Working with modules: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Modules
- Namespace support: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_namespaces